# ng-style did not update dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I tried to use `ng-style` because I need some dynamic color to work on IE11.

```
<tr ng-style="{'background-color':'{{section.Color}}'}">
```

I have a `Angularjs` module that allow me to change color dynamically:

```
<button type="button" colorpicker type="button" colorpicker-position="top" ng-model="section.Color" >
      change color
    </button>
```

Some how it doesn't work. But if it is in normal style, it will update the color. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<tr ng-style="{'background-color':section.Color}">
```

no need to `{{}}` for `section.Color` in `ng-style`

Answer (score 0):

This way

```
<tr ng-style="{'background-color':{{section.Color}} }">
```